# https and http redirection

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have bought a domain, a dedicated IP and ssl certificate. I want to do this -

I want to redirect all these urls -

```
http://webs.agency/
http://www.webs.agency/
https://webs.agency/
```

to https://www.webs.agency/

and the same should be done for all internal pages for example -

```
http://webs.agency/web-design.html
http://www.webs.agency/web-design.html
https://webs.agency/web-design.html
```

to https://www.webs.agency/web-design.html

How it can be done via .htaccess.

I have contacted the hosting company and they said they can't help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to force WWW and HTTPS on everything.

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force WWW on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Force HTTPS on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This should leave you with both `https://www.webs.agency/` and `https://www.webs.agency/web-design.html`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: Change the first `RewriteRule`to `https` to avoid the second rewrite with http without www